# Wallet backup in heterogenous environment

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet.dat

Can we restore a windows environment .dat backup file into linux environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the wallet.dat file, yes, you can do that. There are no Operating System restrictions on the wallet.dat files (or any other files in the Bitcoin Core data directory).

Comment: Yes. I meant wallet.dat file.....Thanks for the reply! :)